# ckeditor clear data when opened in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I am opening ckeditor in a modal. Before opening i want to clear the ckediotr data if any.

I tried adding this code:
 `CKEDITOR.instances.bodyeditor.setData('');`

But this doesn't work.

Any idea on how to clear?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code to do the same.

```
$('#modalID').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    CKEDITOR.instances.bodyeditor.setData('');
});
```

Comment: Yup i tried that, But the data is not getting cleared. SetData does not work. Also i should have told this that i am using insertText for ckeditor. So is it because of that?

Comment: Ya that will add content to your editor. It will be better if you could post your code by editing the question